# How to append rows to sap hana table type?

Tags: types, append, hana

Try to find way to add rows to table type that not empty without removing content.

```
CREATE TYPE "TPU"."TYP_ACTION" AS TABLE 
("ID" BIGINT CS_FIXED, 
"NAME" NVARCHAR(255) CS_STRING)

declare actions "TPU"."TYP_ACTION";
```

The only way i found is:

```
actions=select 1 as id, null as name from dummy;
```

But in this case the previous content of actions will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is: you cannot insert data into a table type.

What you can do - and demonstrated - is to assign data to a table variable that conforms to the type.

As of HANA 2 SPS 01 additional options to change "table variable" data had been added. Now, the table variables can be used in `INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements. See [SAP HANA documentation: Modifying the Content of Table Variables](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.01/en-US/36f718be73e745ceae0530aa80850ce3.html) for details on that.